# prestashop featured products outside columns

Tags: prestashop

In Prestashop, how to show featured products in an individual div, outside columns and homepage main body?

```
<header>
    hook header
</header>
<container>
    <div central_column>
    .
    <!-- here is the featured products block -->
    .
    </div>
    <div right_column>
        hook right column
    </div>
</container>

<newdiv><--! here where i want to show featured products --></newdiv>

<footer>
    hook footer
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new hook, and place that hook in your `<newdiv>`.

After that you need to edit /modules/homefeatured/homefeatured.php and add a hook function for your new hook like

```
function hookYouNewHook($params)
{
    return $this->hookHome($params);
}
```

And the final step is to transplant the homefeatured module to you new hook.

There are lots of guides on how you create new hooks and how to transplat modules.